# what is the Web Service Endpoints of Report Server 2016

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am migrating an application from **SSRS-2012** to **SSRS-2016**. We are having an application to deploy rdl files to the report server. Inside that application we are using Report Server Web Service Endpoints. For SSRS-2012 we used following service url

> http://localhost/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx

When I am migrating to SSRS-2016, what shall be the Report service endpoint?. I didn't find a specific endpoint for SSRS-2016. I confirmed that the same endpoint(above mentioned url-ReportService2010.asmx) is working with SSRS-2016 also.

Anyone please suggest which endpoint should be used with SSRS-2016.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

The endpoint name is the same for SSRS 2012 and SSRS 2016 (ReportService2010).
As described here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/methods/report-server-web-service-endpoints

It only can change if you switch to SSRS 2017 and use the REST API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/developer/rest-api)